# Me.close() not working in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm having trouble with VB. I have a database connected to VB. When I start debugging the connection opens then to close the connection I have a button for it. I also Have a button to close the form. the code in it is `Me.Close()`. It won't work it gives me this error "Property access must assign to the property or use its value"

I can't figure out why, I tried to put it with the close connection button but it gives me the same error.

BTW I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Do you really have `Me.Close.()` or is the last period a typo? Should be `Me.Close()`.

Comment: Beat me by 35 seconds :)

Comment: yes it is a typo, I used `Me.Close()` which is not working

Comment: Is the name of the button "Close"?  See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9951c402-071f-4b21-9a45-11e16575e67f/a-simple-meclose-statement-produces-an-error-what-could-be-the-cause?forum=Vsexpressvb

Comment: No, It's called cmdExit

Comment: Are there any other objects or controls that have the name "Close"?

Comment: yes there is, I'll changed it and see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another object or control with the name "Close" somewhere.  Change the name of that object to resolve the issue.

When there is an object named "Close", `me.close()` will refer to that object, not to the close method of the form, and this error will be returned.

Comment: @musty198 Please accept this as the answer.  I'm shooting for the 200 points in one day badge today!

Answer (score 0):

Unless it was a typo, change:

`Me.Close.()`

to:

`Me.Close()`

to fix the issue.

Comment: Ouch...down voting this answer because of a typo in the original question is very uncool

Comment: Me.Close.() would reflect an error upon compilation, wouldn't it?